# Pass jenkins credentials from pipline to ansible playbook

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline

I try to pass credentials from jenkins pipline to ansible playbook into docker as enviromental variable.

jenkins pipline:

```
steps {
  withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'creds', passwordVariable: 'pass', usernameVariable: 'usr')]) {
    ansiblePlaybook(
      playbook: 'AnsiblePlaybook.yml',
      inventory: 'AnsibleInventory.ini',
      installation: 'ansible-latest',
      disableHostKeyChecking: true,
      become: 'yes',
      extras: '-vvv',
      extraVars: [
        usr: ${usr},
        pass: ${pass}
      ]
    )
  }
}
```

AnsiblePlaybook.yml:

```
docker_container:
  name: mysql
  image: mysql:5.6
  state: started
  env:
    MYSQL_USER: "{{ usr }}"
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: "{{ pass }}"
    MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: "yes"
```

I got error:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method '$' found among steps

Comment: Could be some other problems here, but the first being thrown is that you are using variable string interpolation syntax when there is no string to be interpolated within. Change your `${usr}` to `$usr` and likewise for the pass.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare parameters into variables and use it for building your ansible:

Jenkinsfile parameters: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters-example

Ansible with args: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue.
You had used wrong syntax. 
You forgot `"` 
Here is right example:

```
steps {
  withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'creds', passwordVariable: 'pass', usernameVariable: 'usr')]) {
    ansiblePlaybook(
      playbook: 'AnsiblePlaybook.yml',
      inventory: 'AnsibleInventory.ini',
      installation: 'ansible-latest',
      disableHostKeyChecking: true,
      become: 'yes',
      extras: '-vvv',
      extraVars: [
        usr: "${usr}",  // <================ Here you need extra "
        pass: "${pass}" // <================ Here you need extra "
      ]
    )
  }
}
```